# To grep efficiently by upward recursion

Tags: recursion, grep

**How can you run the following in Grep?**

```
grep "TODO" *
grep "TODO" */*
grep "TODO" */*/*
grep "TODO" */*/*/*
grep "TODO" */*/*/*/*
```

I run unsuccessfully

```
grep -r "TODO"
```

I get what I want by ack-grep by `ack-grep TODO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) recursively, use -R/-r and a path:

```
grep -R "TODO" .
```

So either you're missing the path (.) or I misunderstand your question.

Answer (score 3):

Let the shell do the work:

```
grep "TODO" **/*
```

Answer (score 3):

find . -exec grep -H TODO {} +

Comment: Beware that + is not standard, and not all find implementations support it.  You can always use \;, but it will be less efficient. (More subprocesses will be spawned.)

Comment: This seems to run lots of `grep` processes... might be slow.

Comment: @liori: That's the point of the plus operator - see the manual: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find

Comment: Ah, yes, always forgetting that it differs from \;.

Comment: `-H` seems to be extraneous in Ubuntu's default installation, since it prints the filename for me without it too.